# Is there a way to rank a group of cells based on criteria in excel 2016?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following table in excel, I want to rank the values in B based on the criteria on A. So where ever there is 1 I want only those values ranked against each other.

```
A   B
1   50
2   55
3   88
4   46
3   52
3   32
1   10
1   99
```

How would I do this?

```
A   B   C   
1   50  3   <--- 3rd based on criteria of 1
2   55      
3   88  1   <--- 1st based on criteria of 3
4   46      
3   52  2   <--- 2nd based on criteria of 3
3   32  3   <--- 3rd based on criteria of 3
1   10  2   <--- 2nd based on criteria of 1
1   99  1   <--- 1st based on criteria of 1
```

Comment: Please add your desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to sort use Sumproduct 
A1:A8 first column
B1:B8 second column

in C1 =1+SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$8=A1)*($B$1:$B$8>B1))
and drag it down

Answer (score 0):

If you can sort input table, than it is easy

```
empty row or column header
1   20  1       -- formula in column C =IF(A2<>A1;1;C1+1)
1   40  2       
1   50  3       
1   52  4       
2   10  1       
2   20  2       
2   30  3
```