# How do I rank values based on a criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, sorting

I have survey data for 3619 individuals living in 1000 houses. The MID column is the member ID of each individual. For example: H1M1 is 1st Member of 1st House. H21M3 is 3rd member of 21st house. Column D has House numbers.

I want to do 2 things.

1. Based on age, I want to find the ranking of members in every house.
2. In the next column, I want to find if the member is the eldest kid of the house. Kid is anyone under the age of 18. Binary output of 1 or 0 required.

[image]

Comment: Made an edit to the 2nd point that should clarify. Anyone under the age of 18 is a kid.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to rank a group of cells based on criteria in excel 2016?](https://superuser.com/questions/1055209/is-there-a-way-to-rank-a-group-of-cells-based-on-criteria-in-excel-2016)

Comment: @KaranBarpete,, it's nice one to attempt,, needs some tricky solution,, soon I'll be here with it !

Comment: Hi @Karan Barpete ,, now check my post I've solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

*Below shown method solves the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- To find RANK, formula in cell **D196**:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT((--(LEFT(A196,2)=LEFT($A$196:$A$207,2))),(--(B196<$B$196:$B$207)))+1
  ```
- An array ( CSE ) formula in cell **F196** for *Helper Data:*

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(LEFT(A$196:A$207,2),MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$195:F195,LEFT(A$196:A$207,2)),0)),"")}
  ```

**N.B.** Finish formula with *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*.

- Formula in cell **E196**:

  ```
  =IF(AGGREGATE(14,4,(LEFT($A$196:$A$207,2)=F196)*$B$196:$B$207,1)=0,"",(AGGREGATE(14,4,(LEFT($A$196:$A$207,2)=F196)*$B$196:$B$207,1)))
  ```
- An array (CSE) formula in cell **G196**:

  ```
   {=IF(MIN(IF(LEFT(A$196:A$207,2)=F196,B$196:B$207,""))=0,"",MIN(IF(LEFT(A$196:A$207,2)=F196,B$196:B$207,"")))}
  ```

**N.B.** Finish formula with *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*.

- Formula in cell **H196**:

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(A$196:A$207,MATCH(G196,B$196:B$207,0)),"")
  ```

**N.B.**

- You may also find *name of eldest member*, using formula in cell H196.
- For neatness you may hide *Helper Data*.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `MID` column is sorted by the first two letters of the entry, as you show:

```
AgeRank:    =RANK(G2,INDEX(Age,MATCH(LEFT(F2,2) & "*",MID_,0)):INDEX(Age,-1+MATCH(LEFT(F2,2)&"*",MID_,0)+COUNTIF(MID_,LEFT(F2,2)&"*")))

EldestKid:  =N(G2=AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(INDEX(Age,MATCH(LEFT(F2,2)&"*",MID_,0)):INDEX(Age,-1+MATCH(LEFT(F2,2)&"*",MID_,0)+COUNTIF(MID_,LEFT(F2,2)&"*"))<18)*INDEX(Age,MATCH(LEFT(F2,2)&"*",MID_,0)):INDEX(Age,-1+MATCH(LEFT(F2,2)&"*",MID_,0)+COUNTIF(MID_,LEFT(F2,2)&"*")),1))
```

[image]